# Using mockStatic for Stubbing static method does not work

Tags: junit, mockito, junit-jupiter

I have a static class (ResourceUtils) with this method.

```
static String getVersion(TokenGenerator tokenGenerator, String baseUri)
```

In the Resource class , I am calling the static method, and in the unit test for the resource. I have defined this

```
mockStatic(ResourceUtils.class);
when(ResourceUtils.getVersion(any(), any())).thenReturn("api-2021-01");
```

In the Resource when ResourceUtils.getVersion is called, it calls the actual method instead of executing mock action.

How do i get this to call the stub instead of actual method call.

I tried having before each and using MockStatic and nothing seems to call the stub.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, when you use mockStatic you need to put it in try-with-resources then inside do your stub and you need to continue write code there like verify()

```
try(MockedStatic<ResourceUtils> resourceUtilsMockedStatic = mockStatic(ResourceUtils.class)) {
           resourceUtilsMockedStatic.when(ResourceUtils.getVersion(any(), any())).thenReturn("api-2021-01")
        }
```

Comment: try (var resourceUtilsMockedStatic = Mockito.mockStatic(ResourceUtils.class)) {
      resourceUtilsMockedStatic
          .when(() -> ResourceUtils.getRlaxVersion(any(), any()))
          .thenReturn("api-2021-01");
      Response postResponse =
          folderResourceExt
              .target("/import/v1/folders/10/files/100/transform")
              .request()
              .header("Authorization", TOKEN)
              .post(Entity.entity(transformInputJsonBody, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE));
     This actually calls the original method instead of stub and gives me error.

Comment: because you need to mock .post() method too. If you can provide more info, especially all code related to your method. so I would try to help you

Comment: My Resource is this --  Annotations here. public Response createTransformJob(
  
          int bucketId,
     int fileId,
     ExcelFile excelFileInfo) {
    try {
     <<code here>>

      String apiVersion = ResourceUtils.getRlaxVersion(tokenGenerator, rlaxBase);

      <<code >>
      } My unit test is above what i wrote above

Answer (score 0):

The scope of the static mock needs to be defined in a scope using a try-with-resources block

```
try(MockedStatic<ResourceUtils> utils = mockStatic(ResourceUtils.class)) {
    utils.when(() -> ResourceUtils.getVersion(any(), any())).thenReturn("api-2021-01");
}
```